# returning all array's index swift

Tags: swift

I have a list of activityPercentage inside my entity and I iterated all of the value as a CGFloat. but the code below takes only the last value inside chartData array.

screenshot :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1b5e6xlle4ivqp/Screenshot%202015-02-28%2014.02.06.png?dl=0

```
func barChartView(barChartView: JBBarChartView!, heightForBarViewAtIndex index: UInt) -> CGFloat {

        var activityPers: Int?
        for activity in chartData{
            activityPers = activity.activityPercentage as? Int
        }
        return CGFloat(activityPers!)

    }
```

please help, I want to return all the percentage in every bar not just the last activityPercentage entered.

How can I store this line in an Array, because I need an array variable to access the subscript index

```
activityPers = activity.activityPercentage as? Int
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the height only for the requested `index`. The method will be called separately for each bar with a different value for `index`.

Comment: the activityPercentage is the reference of my height, I need to return all value under activityPercentage.

Comment: @shaideru The method will be called separately for each bar, you can't and you shouldn't return all of them at once. You must only return the height of the bar at `index`, e.g., if you have 10 bars the function will be called with 10 different values of `index` and each time you return one value but different every time. The return type is a single `CGFloat`, you can't return more than one value from it.

Comment: it worked when I used "return CGFloat(chartData[Int(index)])" all the value in my array returned. but now I am trying to fetch values from data core, and I am lost.

Comment: `return CGFloat(chartData[Int(index)])` returns only one value as well, the one at `index`. In your current version the problem is that you are trying to return more than one value, but you _must_ return only one. Use `index` to determine which one.

Comment: Oh, now I understand,  so do you have any idea how to return index inside the core data? similar to this "return CGFloat(chartData[Int(index)])"

Comment: I don't know the format of your data, perhaps it's something like `chartData[index].activityPercentage` converted to `CGFloat`.

Comment: var chartData = [ActivityEntity](), and activity percentage is one of the object inside ActivityEntity.

Answer (score 0):

got it!

```
 var data: NSManagedObject = chartData[Int(index)] as NSManagedObject

    var percentageFloat = data.valueForKeyPath("activityPercentage") as Int
    return CGFloat(percentageFloat)
```